# SQL Server index on optional columns

Tags: sql-server, indexing, query-optimization

In my scenario i have a table with a lot of optional columns (20 columns in total, say form col00 to col19, every column contain an integer not nullable).
When the column contains a 0 it's considered empty any other values have a meaning.
Any subset of that 20 columns could be queried, so i should query for col01 = int1 and col17 = int2.

I need to improve the performance of such queries, but i don't know how to create a representative index.
Surely i can monitor table for a while and see which columns subset are searchest most, but this is not a satisfiable solution to me (the table is periodically regenerated every few months..and the "tags" encoded that way may change)

Comment: Are there any columns that always get passed?

Comment: No, each column may be ( not every customer use all the columns) bound to a tag set, a tag set is a range of allowed values usable as tag in that column. Eg: first column for color tag, second columns for size tag.. and so on. If someone will query for a red item, sized n inches I'll have to check first and second column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best you'll be able to do is to index every column by itself, then use the set operator INTERSECT... in a subquery of your where clause.

INTERSECT returns distinct rows that are output by both the left and right input queries operator. So if you select the primary key of the table in the INTERSECT then you should have a good subquery that can be used in a where-clause. This will require you to re-write your queries however.

Example:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tablename
 WHERE primary_key = (
SELECT primary_key FROM tablename WHERE col01 = int1 
INTERSECT 
SELECT primary_key FROM tablename WHERE col17 = int2
)
```

That should be sargable, if col01 and col17 have their own index.